# Bootstrap js refuses to load

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, twitter-bootstrap

I've used a small javascript file to create an off canvas push navbar. I loaded the file as described in the Wordpres Codex:

```
function sidebar () {
wp_enqueue_script('theme-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/nav-sidebar.js',array( 'jquery' ),$version,true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sidebar');
```

However, it seems that the only js that is loaded is the nav-sidebar and the bootstrap.js refuses to load. If i remove nav-sidebar.js, bootstrap.js loads just fine. It creates a conflict that i can't solve.

You can find the script i've used [here](http://jsbin.com/pecefezigo/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Did you call your `bootstrap.js` file `theme-js` too? Also add the code where you include the `boostrap.js` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding [@RRikesh](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/17305/rrikesh) comment, you might have enqueued/loaded the `bootstap.js` with same handle `theme-js`. So only one script gets enqueued.

Try to use different handle for example `nav-sidebar`. See the following code. Also it's recommended to use prefix, here I used `wpse`. Also use `get_template_directory_uri` instead of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` if it's not a child theme.

```
function wpse_sidebar () {
   wp_enqueue_script('nav-sidebar', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/nav-sidebar.js',array( 'jquery' ),'1.0.0',true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_sidebar');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have already enqueued bootstrap js in your theme functions.php with handle named 'bootstrapjs' in the same way you did with nav-sidebar.js, which you didn't mentioned. Now make a little change to your code.

```
function sidebar(){
wp_enqueue_script('theme-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/nav-sidebar.js', array( 'jquery','bootstrapjs' ),$version, true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sidebar');
```

Other possible reason you haven't enqueued the bootstrap js properly. Also check for 404 error.